# Thyme leaf-SpringBoot-Targetting Map.Entry within Map property of Form-bound object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Can't find any example or way to do this, and finally registered to this forum for help! 
My application is a Questionnaire - I display questions and users select answer from a drop down list. 
I have two Model Attributes 
1) a list of Question objects "questionList" is variable name in the Model 
2) salesResponse is the variable name of the other attribute - its an object of SalesResponse class. 
SalesResponse has a property called "responses" which is a TreeMap. It has a default constructor, and setter/getter for "responses". 
On POST, the key should be the question's ID, and the value should be the value of option selected. 
So, should be TreeMap. This is the Map I'd like to be populated in my salesResponse object when user does a POST.

My controller loads these two objects into the context...I'm not sure how to write the form! Here is roughly what I need:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/ehc}" th:object="${salesResponse}"
method="post">
<table>
  <tr th:each="question: ${questionList}">
    <td th:text="${question.questionText}" th:value="${question.ID}"  
        th:name=${..what??..}
        th:field="*{THIS SHOULD BECOME the KEY in responses TreeMap}"></td>
    <td><select th:field="*{THIS SHOULD BECOME THE VALUE in responses TreeMap}">
      <option th:text="${question.option1}" th:value="2"></option>
      <option th:text="${question.option2}" th:value="4"></option>
      <option th:text="${question.option3}" th:value="6"></option>         
    </select> 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td><input type="reset" value="reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

How should this be written? Will Spring be smart enough to populate the responses TreeMap, One Map.Entry at a time?

EDIT: I tried this, and it didn't work (Got this exception), but maybe it gives someone inspiration to solve this! 
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "iterStat.index"`

Trial code:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/ehc}" th:object="${salesResponse}"
method="post">
<table>
<tr th:each="question,iterStat: ${questionList}">
    <td><input type="number" readonly="readonly"
        th:text="${question.questionText}" th:name="${responses}" 
        th:value="${question.ID}" 
        th:field="*{responses[iterStat.index].key}"/></td>
    <td><select th:field="*{responses[iterStat.index].value}">
      <option th:text="${question.option1}" th:value="2"></option>
      <option th:text="${question.option2}" th:value="4"></option>
      <option th:text="${question.option3}" th:value="6"></option>         
    </select> 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td><input type="reset" value="reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of sleepless nights, I've got this working, and documenting it so that someone else trying this would benefit:
Here is the code from the view:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/ehc}" th:object="${salesResponse}" 
method="post">

<table>
<tr th:each="entry,iterStat: ${responses}">
  <td th:text="${salesResponse.questionList[iterStat.index].questionText}"></td>
  <td><select th:name="'responses[' + ${entry.key} +']'">
<!--  <td><select th:field="*{responses[__${entry.key}__]}">-->
      <option selected="selected" th:text="${salesResponse.questionList[iterStat.index].option1}"
                                  th:value="2" ></option>
      <option th:text="${salesResponse.questionList[iterStat.index].option2}"
              th:value="4" ></option>
      <option th:text="${salesResponse.questionList[iterStat.index].option3}"
              th:value="6" ></option>         
    </select> 
  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td><input type="reset" value="reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

The key factor was getting the select tag correct. When the HTML is rendered, you can see "responses[n]" in the select's name field. That essentially refers to the 'Key' of the resulting map and the value field is the corresponding Value.
Now, having done this, I did notice that when I used "th:field" my responses getter was been called 300 times for just 15 entries in the Map. I replaced the th:field with a th:name to generate the same html, and now its been called 15 times only. Tried searching for a reason online, but haven't found anything. Right now through, I'm happy to move on since spending so much time on this roadblock!